# Can't place an element in ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

There's the following problem: when I place an elment in ActionBar, it's not showed separately from other elements, but with the rest elemnts, which shouldn't be showed separately. showAsAction is always, that's why don't understand why it shows so.

There's a menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_create_new_order"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And there's a way how I connect this menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not showed with the other elements." This question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @DylanBurton. Sorry for my English, but I tried to say that I want to place it on AndroidBar as separated item, but in my situation if you want to click on this item, you  should to click on ... (but vertical) (I actually don't know how it's called, but I think you understand me) and only after you can click on this item. And I want to make it clicked in one click from ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

From `onCreateOptionsMenu` return `true`